# Unset attribute value for a specific product magento

Tags: php, magento

I have an attribute "Clothes" with multiselect options "Skirt","Pant","Cargos"...

The attribute id's are say,

skirt-198
pant-199
cargos-200

I have to tag a collection of products with attribute skirt, i do it this way,

```
$collection->setClothes('198');
$collection->save();
```

Now i want to tag the same collection with the attribute pant as well,

if i use,

```
$collection->setClothes('199');
```

it overwrites and now the product is tagged only to pants and not to both skirts and pants.

I need help in rightly tagging a product with multiple attributes(when multiselect is used)

And another case is where, I have a product tagged to skirts and I want to untag it from skirts.

I have tried my best. Can someone pls help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `$collection->setClothes(array('198','199'));`?

and to untag, you simply have to:

```
$tags = $collection->getClothes(); //let's say we have 5 tags.. 192, 193, 194, 199, 198.

$tagsToRemove = array('194','199');

$collection->setClothes(
    array_diff($tags, $tagsToRemove)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But if I have to untag an attribute, how should i do it.Right now, i'm using
    $collection->setClothes(' ');
and what is the magento table that is used to specify the attributes linked to a particular table. Your reply would be very helpful.